# Fetch a string response in afnetworking iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, afnetworking

I am using a web service which is returning response in string format, below is the response form

```
URLdecoded token: PjXoTuRmatcMCFXgQ43Jr8vb4Ux9mdqJyxYsVZ170NS76Q== 
base64 decoded in byte: [B@16c1d8a7 random code in byte: [B@1076c79d newhash in byte: [B@662b1cdc concatData in byte: [B@1873e3eb Base64.encodeBase64String(concatData): PjXoTuRmatcMCFXgQ43Jr8vb4Ux9mdqJyxYsVZ170NS76Q== 
localToken: PjXoTuRmatcMCFXgQ43Jr8vb4Ux9mdqJyxYsVZ170NS76Q%3D%3D 
sms code: 225182;  
OK - International
```

My question is how to fetch it as currently its going in failure block and error is shown that response is not object type.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: What's your code? What did you put as responseSerializer?

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: Above is error i am getting

Comment: manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes= [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]; using this as response serializer

Comment: Try this-  manager.responseSerializer = [[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

Comment: thanks @DipankarDas for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this- `manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];`

Comment: manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

Answer (score 0):

You might to do things like followed:

```
AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[serializer setStringEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
manager.requestSerializer=serializer;
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

In your success block, you need to init your string via responseObject, like this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Here string is your correct response.